# HashLocationStrategy and query parameters in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am migrating an existing angular 4 app from PathLocationStrategy to `HashLocationStrategy` and need to keep entry point url working. It looks something like `www.test.com/?param1=123`

The problem is that as soon as I switch it to HashLocationStrategy, query params are not accessible through activatedRoute.queryParams anymore. (`www.test.com/#/?param1=123` works fine but I need to preserve the original url entry as well)

So is there a way to get param1 value from `www.test.com/?param1=123` with `HashLocationStrategy`? I don't really want to create an empty landing page that will redirect to `www.test.com/#/?param1=123` unless I can't avoid it.

Comment: Route changes usually imply that old urls will be redirected to new ones, so yes, in general it makes sense to do this from server side. There can be not only legacy root path like `/?param1=123`, but also other paths like `/foo/bar`, right? The use of HashLocationStrategy often means that the app is not SPA. Is it? A url like `/?param1=123#/?param1=456` can exist in theory, so it depends on how exactly this should be handled.

Comment: I only care about the entry url, the rest urls don't matter and can change. The reason for moving HashLocationStrategy is that we've got a SPA served from an S3 bucket, and it gets tricky to add server side support for the urls that Angular creates otherwise. Server side redirection doesn't work well with # in the url

Comment: It works well. There are problems with reading # from server side but no problems with setting it. It's possible to do this inside Angular, but I'd say it's much cleaner from server side. You can just set Location header to `'/#' + currentUrl` when currentUrl is not `/`, and it will cover all SPA urls.

Comment: I had issues with that in the past. From memory IE doesn't understand # part of the url on 302

Comment: From my experience, IE versions that are supported by Angular (10-11) don't have problems like that. Usually this kind of redirections should be done from server side but yes, it's possible to do this in Angular.

Comment: possibly that's past days and now outdated versions of IE. I'll keep that as a plan B :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `HashLocationStrategy` is already used as default, `PathLocationStrategy` should be additionally injected in order to get to real browser location:

```
  providers: [
    PathLocationStrategy,
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
    ...
  ]

...

class AppComponent {
  constructor(router: Router, pathLocationStrategy: PathLocationStrategy) {
    const basePath = pathLocationStrategy.getBaseHref();
    const absolutePathWithParams = pathLocationStrategy.path();

    if (basePath !== absolutePathWithParams) {
      router.navigateByUrl(absolutePathWithParams);
    }
  }
}
```

If there is base url, it should be additionally taken away from the path.

Comment: Can't get this to work for some reason. As soon as I have HashLocationStrategy defined as default (`imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],` ) both basePath and absolutePathWithParams are empty strings.

Comment: I cannot confirm this. As you can see here, it works as expected, even in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/rEWLGykANUMReFqNVPno?p=preview

Comment: oh thanks so much with plunker. I figured out I should be doing redirect in the AppComponent while I was trying to setup a separate component on '' route.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it should be done before route change is triggered.