# Azure OAuth2 fails with Angular HashLocationStrategy

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, hash-location-strategy

This is a follow up question to [Angular App Hosting Azure Storage Container - Azure Authentication Callback and Routing fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59818707/angular-app-hosting-azure-storage-container-azure-authentication-callback-and).

Summary:

I want to host my Angular 8 app on an Azure Storage Account. To make the routing work I had to turn on the HashLocationStrategy. This strategy prefixes the routes with a hashtag like this: `https://<projectname>.z6.web.core.windows.net/#/auth/login`

The routing works now but the Azure OAuth2 process adds the access token information to the base url also by using a hashtag: `<baseurl>/<callbackurl>#access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...`.
Without using the HashLocationStrategy the route would be like this (callback route is `/auth/callback`):

```
https://<projectname>.z6.web.core.windows.net/auth/callback#access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...
```

With HashLocationStrategy it should be like this:

```
https://<projectname>.z6.web.core.windows.net/#/auth/callback#access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...
```

But what it does is this:

```
https://<projectname>.z6.web.core.windows.net/#access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...
```

It just swallows the callback url part and adds the access_token part directly behind the base url. The redirect fails.

Is there a way to make Azure OAuth2 work with HashLocationStrategy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not investigated all the facets of your question nor have I needed to leverage HashLocationStrategy, but on S3 buckets we've specified the custom 404 page to point to the index.html file, similar to a suggestion in the Angular [Deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) documentation for use in static GitHub Pages.

In Azure's [Static website hosting in Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website#setting-up-a-static-website) page, it indicates that a custom 404 page can be specified. You could try to specify the index.html file as well. This effectively "actives" the Angular router on non URL-rewritable hosting - at least this worked on S3 static site hosting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You added the same link twice. Can you please fix the Angular Deployment link?

Comment: Sure, I fixed the link.

Comment: Thank you very much! Copying the index.html and renaming the copy to 404.html made it :-) It works, woohoo!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're trying to put a square peg in a round hole!

You tried to use `HashLocationStrategy` because you can't redirect Angular routes to `index.html` when using Azure Storage as a web server.

However, you're using OAuth, which always provides the token in an URL fragment. This is to keep the `access_token` away from the app server, since the browser doesn't send it at all, after receiving it in the redirection from the identity provider.

I don't see any workaround to help you achieve what you're trying, I'm afraid you'll have to host the app on a "URL rewriting capable" web server.

Comment: So there is no possibility to use OAuth2 with Angular apps that are hosted at Azure Storage?

Comment: I didn't take time to explore all of the possibilities but I strongly doubt this is possible

Answer (score 0):

Use **`&response_mode=query`** instead of the default *fragment*.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-the-sign-in-request

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=https://<projectname>.z6.web.core.windows.net/auth/callback // escape this..
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid
&state=12345
&nonce=7362CAEA-9CA5-4B43-9BA3-34D7C303EBA7
```

Your response should now look like this:

```
https://<projectname>.z6.web.core.windows.net/auth/callback?access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this does not work: "The application requested an unsuported mode "query" when requesting a token".

Comment: My bad, this does not work for SPA. It only works for Authorization Code Flow... glad someone else was able to help you